# Running a remote cmd command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, remote-access, powershell-remoting

I uploaded some files to a remote host with PowerShell, by FTP. On this host runs [Windows 7 Embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_Compact_7).

It turns out there is EWF (Enhanced Write Filter). So after a restart the uploaded files were gone. For saving the changes it needs commit them in cmd (at the remote host) by: `ewfmgr d:-commit` How can I include this command in my PowerShell code?

The code:

```
  Enable-PSRemoting -Force
        Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value * -Force
        Restart-Service WinRm
        Test-WSMan $line
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $line -scriptblock {cmd.exe /c "ewfmgr d: -commit"} -credential $FTPCredential
```

When I run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` manually on the remote computer, it works, but it is uncomfortable and take lots of time. Is there another way to do this once for many hosts simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Example-Code:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName yourRemoteComputer
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {ewfmgr d: -commit}
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

You have to enable Powershell Remoting on your host to invoke a command like this (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

If you need to transmit Credentials to your remote host, you can add the -Credential-Parameter to New-PSSession. This article describes how to add valid Credentials to your script (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

Greetings, Ronny

Comment: OK, but there is in remote host (Win 7 Embedded) no powershell, only DOS cmd.